# NoReturn vs. None in "void" functions - type annotations in Python 3.6

Tags: python, annotations, python-3.6, type-hinting, typing

Python 3.6 supports type annotation, like:

```
def foo() -> int:
    return 42
```

But what is expected to use when a function hasn't return anything? [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) examples mostly use `None` as a return type, but there is also `NoReturn` type from `typing` package.

So, the question is what is preferable to use and what is considered a best practice:

```
def foo() -> None:
    #do smth
```

or

```
from typing import NoReturn

def foo() -> NoReturn:
    #do smth
```

Comment: The type of `None` is not `None`, but `NoneType`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, according to PEP484, `None` is considered equivalent to `type(None)` what is `NoneType`, in a type hint.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`NoReturn` means the function *never returns a value*.

The function either *does not terminate or always throws an exception*: ["The typing module provides a special type NoReturn to annotate functions that never return normally. For example, a function that unconditionally raises an exception.."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-noreturn-type).

```
from typing import NoReturn

def stop() -> NoReturn:
    raise RuntimeError('no way')
```

That is, `x = foo_None()` is type-valid but suspect while `x = foo_NoReturn()` is invalid.

Besides never having an assignable result, `NoReturn` also has other implications in branch analysis: `foo_NoReturn(); unreachable..`. There is further discussion in the ['A `NoReturn` type is needed #165'](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/165) ticket.

> In order to perform branch analysis, it is necessary to know which calls will never return normally. Examples are `sys.exit` (which always returns via exception) and `os.exit` (which never returns)..

Comment: curiously, for a function that _might_ throw an exception, `Optional[NoReturn]` doesn't pass mypy ("error: Missing return statement"), even though the function either doesn't return or returns `None` ... perhaps it's sth to do with `NoReturn` also being the bottom type

Comment: @joel: because, at least conceptually, `NoReturn` is not a type per se, is an indication of _**absense of type**_ because there is no associated value, not even `None`. It's not even assignable, so you possiblly can't (at least certainly _shouldn't_) use it in `Union`, `TypeAlias`, etc.

Comment: @MestreLion I don't follow; a type doesn't have to have values to be a type. `Void` in Idris and `Nothing` in Scala are examples. I can't see any type-theoretic reason that you shouldn't use it in a `Union`. Granted it's not very useful esp in python, but I'd think it valid

Comment: @joel True, conceptually a type does not require a value. But in the context of `f(...) -> type:` annotations, we are referring to the _type of the returned **value**_. It has a very specific meaning, not a general annotation of _how_, _when_, or _if_ a function exits. Allowing so requires changing the _semantics_ of `->`, as described by PEP

Comment: so when to use `-> None`?

Comment: `def foo():`
        `print('hello')`

also "never returns a value". Do we use `-> NoReturn` in this case?

Comment: @OliverAngelil You use `-> None` for a function that returns `None`. That sounds obvious, of course. What I overlooked when I started type annotating my own code is that a function with no explicit `return` statement will have an _implicit_ `return None`. So, your example function would be `def foo() -> None`. Same if you have a `return` with no argument: the arg to `return` is implicitly `None`.

Comment: Consider that "returning a value" means giving some value back to the caller, even if it's a `None`. `NoReturn` means that the function doesn't give anything back to the caller, including the top of the call stack. If there weren't exception handling, it would be like an infinite loop because the interpreter would never leave the function's stack frame. When you `raise`, you're telling the interpreter "if the caller can't recover this condition, drop the entire call stack and stop." That's why `try/except` is considered to be part of control flow, like `if` or `for`.