# 'Missing return statement' in simple conditional structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

The return type of the below function depends on the argument passed to `path`: if it is `None` the function returns a string, if it is a string the function returns `None`, and in all other possible cases, the function does not return at all. However, `mypy` reports

> error: Missing return statement

What am I missing here?

```
import json
from typing import Optional

def to_json(data: dict, path: Optional[str] = None) -> Optional[str]:
    if path is None:
        return json.dumps(data)
    elif isinstance(path, str):
        with open(path, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file)
    else:
        raise TypeError('Unsupported type for ``path``.')
```

Comment: just make `return None` explicit

Comment: @ybl a `TypeError` is raised if path it is not a string.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am aware of this possibility. However, I don't understand why mypy forces me to do so.

Comment: btw your flow doesn't look consistent to me because of absolutely different behaviors based on type of argument

Comment: Unrelated, but `NoReturn` is for functions that don't return, not for functions that return no value (use `None` for that). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48038149/857390).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mypy` warns on missing return types by default, so you can turn it off explicitly:

```
$ mypy --no-warn-no-return spam.py
```

or turn off the particular check for the particular line only:

```
def to_json(data: Dict, path: Optional[str] = None) -> Optional[str]:  # type: ignore[return]
    ...
```

However, your function has different return types depending on the input. I would add an overloaded signature to handle these:

```
from typing import Dict, Optional, overload

# when path is provided, the function returns
@overload
def to_json(data: Dict, path: str) -> str: ...

# when path is not provided, the function returns None
@overload
def to_json(data: Dict) -> None: ...

# your actual impl
def to_json(data, path=None):
    if path is None:
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

not explicitly returning something from all branches makes the static analysis fail: it's seen as an omission (and considered as bad practice).

Just make the `return None` explicit in the `else` part (no need where you're rasing an exception)

```
elif isinstance(path, str):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, your code is valid python. I believe mypy seems to be configured according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) recommendations for returns but is more strict about it since it has to enforce typechecks. The relevant section:

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a
>   function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any
>   return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no
>   value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an
>   explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function
>   (if reachable).

Yes:

```
def foo(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)
    else:
        return None
```

No:

```
def foo(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)
```

---

So, for your code, just be explicit about `return None` in all branches where you do not return anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return None` to the code or `return -1` or any such kind of return at the end of code.