# Should a Python function that doesn't return a value have `-> None` in its signature?

Tags: python, mypy

When writing a typed function in Python that does not return a value (like "void" in other languages), is it best and/or conventional to mark it as follows?

```py
def say_hello(name: str) -> None
    print(f"Hello, {name}.")
```

Alternatively, should one just omit the `-> None`?

```py
def say_hello(name: str)
```

I suppose what I'm asking is whether omitting the `-> None` leaves the return type unspecified, or it is assumed to be `NoneType` anyway, and thus unnecessary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038149/noreturn-vs-none-in-void-functions-type-annotations-in-python-3-6

Comment: @rdas Vaguely related, but not the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python void return type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797282/python-void-return-type-annotation)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Between that and the answer below, all good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python void return type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797282/python-void-return-type-annotation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The default for a missing annotation is `Any`, not `None`.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-meaning-of-annotations) If you leave out the return annotation, type checkers will treat your function as returning `Any`.

> For a checked function, the default annotation for arguments and for the return type is Any.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Is this documented somewhere? (Just out of curiosity, not that I don't believe you!)

Comment: @Noldorin: Citation added.

Comment: Cheers. Will accept the answer soon, when it's permitted.