# Pycharm provide unreachable code because of NoReturn type hint

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pytest

I am writing a test for a code that will raise an exception.

```
with pytest.raises(Exception) as exception:
    A.b()

assert str(exception.value) == "exception"
```

The function `b` will never return a thing and may raise an exception.
Once I put the return type of `b()` to `def b() -> NoReturn:` I am getting that the assertion will never be reached "This code is unreachable". Either I did not get the purpose of NoReturn or It is a bug in Pycharm, because once I debug it, the line is reachable.

An example of b is

```
def b(a: int) -> NoReturn:
    if a < 0:
        raise Exception('Negative numbers are not accepted)
```

Comment: So it sounds like a bug in Pycharm, but also, it sounds like you misunderstood `NoReturn`, what do you mean by "The function b will never return a thing and may raise an exception." What do you mean by "may"? If it doesn't always raise an exception, then it *has to return something*

Comment: What do you suggest as a type hint for a function that conditionally raises an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"will never return a thing and may raise an exception"* contradicts itself. A function can't "never return a thing" and "may raise an exception" at the same time.

Even if a function does not explicitly use the `return` statement, `None` is implicitly returned.

You should change `NoReturn` in the type hint to `None`.

Comment: I think None is similar to Null in Java; for instance `return None`. But in my case, the function never return.

Comment: @Mounir Then what does it do? Show its code. As I wrote, even if there is no `return` statement in the function it still returns `None`.

Comment: I have added the code to the post. could you check it.

Comment: check this post please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038149/noreturn-vs-none-in-void-functions-type-annotations-in-python-3-6

Comment: In case you are suggesting that NoReturn is only used when the function raises an exception, please let me know.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you. It is a None type here.